# How to run command line in c

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Im trying to create a snapshot of the WebCacheV01.dat database for dumping MEdge history. 
I use this command for that:

```
esentutl.exe /y /vss C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat /d C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ESEDatabase\WebCacheV01_Copy.dat
```

It run very well on cmd with admin privileges. But now i want to run the command in my code, i call system() and pass the command in but nothing happend. I also try:

```
ShellExecuteA(0, "runas", "cmd", "/c esentutl.exe /y /vss C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\WebCache\\WebCacheV01.dat /d C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\WebCacheV01_Copy.dat", 0, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

But still nothing. I try to run my code as admin but still nothing.

Comment: Your program probably needs elevation.

Comment: What error did it return?

Comment: Why are you executing cmd? Why don't you run the program directly. Also, use ShellExecuteEx so you can have proper error handling. And then check the return value.

Comment: It execute my command but esentutl need admin to run so it fail at that point

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteA(0, "runas", "cmd",.................)`，it will open cmd as an administrator and point to .exe file that requires administrator privileges.All you need to do is check the return value of `ShellExecute` to determine what caused the error.

Comment: Thanks guys, My solution is disable Wow64 redirect. I still dont know why my command run perfectly in C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe but not in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (both run as admin).